# Hard to start push key ignition

Tags: starting, diesel, audi, a4

My car is a Audi A4 TDI 2.0 manual 2008. It is hard to start. When I push in the key and put my foot on the clutch peddle it won't start. When I push in the key, put my foot on the brake peddle, and put the car into reverse, it will start. Two weeks ago I had to replace the cable from the battery up to the engine as the cable was burned out ... now this problem is happening. Can you help?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!